# How do I call a function when going back to a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having problems trying to figure out how to call a function when I am going back to a page, maybe you can help me. In my bossHandler file I have it for when the boss's HP reaches 0, it calls back to my storyPage.html file and continues where the story left off. This is what I have:

bossHandler.js

```
if(currMonster.currHp <= 0) {
    currMonster.currHp = 0;
    alert("You have killed " + currMonster.name + "! \n You gained " + currMonster.gold + " gold!!!")
    myChar.gold += currMonster.gold;
    updateCookie(myChar);
    loadPageWithNumber(17);
}
```

On my storyPage.js I have

```
function loadPageWithNumber(pageNumber){
    window.location ="storyPage.html";
    nextStoryText(pageNumber);
}
```

but the problem I am getting is that it is calling `nextStoryText()` before the new page has loaded. I've tried a few things and also tried changing the page back in the if statement and then calling `nextStoryText()` from my bossHandler.js file and that still didn't work. Tried looking around on here for a solution but I kept finding ways to just go back to the page and call an onload event, but I don't want a event to fire every time I load that page. Is there a easy way to do this?

Also, my storyPage.html is the first page I'm on until an encounter starts, then it heads to my bossPage.html. Once the boss is dead I want to go BACK to storyPage.html and that's the problem I'm having currently.

Comment: Just an idea: modify the cookie on bossHandler.js with some value, navigate to the next page, check this cookie, if it is set don't execute `nextStoryText()` but instead `loadPageWithNumber()`.

Comment: That seemed to fix my problem.